# show text field attribute of a configurable product magento

Tags: magento

I have added configurable product and added textarea attribute to it, I want to show the attributes at front end in my custon view, how can I show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <col width="25%" />
    <col />
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label">
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label']))    ?></th>
            <td class="data">
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'],
 $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage Attribute -> *Select your attribute* -> Visible on Product View Page on Front-end -> Select "YES"

Does this solve your problem?